# Listen audio track with mic to get it's current timestamp

Tags: java

here's my pain:
I have known audio track (mp3 song) and need my device to listen it with microphone to get current playing timestamp in milliseconds.

There's some libs and services to compare audios, but I can't find anything to get stream timestamp, can you show me some direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use native libraries, OpenAL has at least these two Java wrappers:

- [JOAL](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php)
- [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/)

And may you try the [Java Sound API](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasounddemo-140014.html) ?

Comment: Yes, thank you, but still looking for some ready-to-go library

Comment: It is the case of JOAL => [How to get the source code](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Joal_FAQ#How_do_I_get_the_Source_Code.3F)